# Alternative to blur() for setting window focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I am using a little bit of Javascript to set the focus of a window to the background.  I am asking a user if they want to take a survey.  If so, the survey window should fall behind the active window so they can continue to surf the site unabated.  The JS works fine, except for in Chrome (and probably Safari).

Here's the JS:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  self.blur();
};
```

Is there a better way to do this that has better browser acceptance?

Comment: I believe you're looking for a "Pop-under" window. (_See [this page](http://www.codeave.com/javascript/code.asp?u_log=7068)_)

Comment: That is using blur() which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no standard or reliable way to force the window manager to position a popup window below its parent on all platforms.

If you're into unobtrusive surveys, you might want to consider implementing [something](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/notification) [like](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/notification-bar) StackOverflow's notification bar, and opening your popup window in the foreground only if the user interacts with that element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That may be the right direction to move in, however for now the survey is only served to a small percentage of people and it is supposed to be a bit intrusive.

Comment: "a bit"? Sorry but this is not 1998 anymore. Manipulating the user's windows focus is A LOT intrusive.

Comment: @Peachy, not only is @Capsule right on the principle, but your question implies that you want to support as many platforms as possible. If so, that's not the way to go. Consider users who tabify everything, including popups, for instance. Or [tiling window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager), that don't even *know* what z-order is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the survey window in front of another window, and want it to go behind that window if user elects to take the survey.
Try this:

```
<BODY onLoad="self.blur()">
```